# Finding all solutions to a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to get all the solutions to the question:
$\sin(z) =2$
Where $z=x+iy$
I know that in real space, the sine function only takes values from - 1 to 1 but in the complex space, it's not limited. I tried to work it out this way:

$\sin(z) = (e^{iz}  - e^{-iz}) /2i$

$e^{iz} - e^{-iz}=4i$

But I'm stuck here because the above equation yields an unfamiliar quadratic equation in the form of
$X^2 - 4iX - 1=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the quadratic equation:

You will get $X=(2\pm\sqrt{3})i$

Now, $$X=e^{iz}=(2\pm\sqrt{3})i\tag{1}$$

Let $z=x+iy$, then $$e^{iz}=e^{i(x+iy)}=e^{ix-y}=e^{-y}\cos(x)+ie^{-y}\sin(x)$$

From $(1)$ you can see that $X$ is purely imaginary. Use this fact to find $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I can proceed from there. And thank you very much. I just want to know how you solved that complex quadratic

Comment: Use the quadratic formula. It works for equations with complex coefficients too.

Comment: Ohh. Okay. Thanks again

Comment: @user607715: No. **Do not use the quadratic formula.** Instead understand how the quadratic formula works (by completing the square) so that you can **see for yourself** that it works for any quadratic equation over a field where $2$ has a multiplicative inverse (such as rationals or reals or complex numbers), and the existence of the roots depends on merely the existence of the one square-root needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\sin(x+iy)=\sin \left( x \right) \cosh \left( y \right) +i\cos \left( x \right) 
\sinh \left( y \right) 
$$